# MySQL PrimaryKey AutoIncrement

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

i have the following problem:

I make an insert to a table. The primaryKey is auto incremented and is an integer.

1. In one table i have an index of 2345 and suddenly it is updated to 10000.
2. In another table i have an index of 263564 and it is updated to 1000000.

Does anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

If your inserted value contains field with autoincrement, your key will be updated.

You can change your auto increment value

```
ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 100;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-auto-increment.html

Also, here is two system variables, which controls behavior of autoincrement.

`auto_increment_increment` controls the interval between successive column values.
`auto_increment_offset` determines the starting point for the AUTO_INCREMENT column value

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment

Answer (score 0):

It was an internal problem. Some Testcases manipulated the Id.

Thanks for your help.